# Is there any SQLite Caching mechanism in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

I want to cache the data/objects after getting them from a `SQLite DB` instead of querying it multiple times. Is there any such functionality available in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for **comparatively small** data. It stores data in key value pairs. It limits to 1mb for app I guess... So good option for you if you don't have large datasets.

You can save your object in the form of JSON as well, which require you to write a layout that converts you object form plain java to json and vice versa.

Keep using SQLite if you have large size of data in you queries.